# Linux, MongoDB: Open failed: administratively prohibited, but only for port 27017

Tags: linux, mongodb

I am receiving the error `Open failed: administratively prohibited` when trying to connect to a `mongodb` database over ssh.

From other SO posts it seems that this might be caused by a variable `AllowTcpConnections yes` in `/etc/sshd/sshd_config`.

So I made sure the variable was correctly set on my server - I also tried with other port (like 8888 for jupyter notebook, or other and they did work!)

Is there anything specific to mongodb / or that port regarding that matter?

Comment: people putting -1: can you add a comment explaining why? Question might be stupid, but I'm stuck...

Comment: Port 27017 is the default port for MongoDB. My guess is that you already have an instance running. Perhaps some time in your past, you installed and setup an instance of MongoDB that automatically turns on with your computer. Can you connect with the command line `mongod` command? Otherwise, do a port scan on 27017 and see what else might be running there. You need to free it up so you can use it if that's your requirement.

Comment: Is this a remote connection between two different computers or all on the localhost? Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open

Comment: @ThisClark  yes, 2 different computers (one is a aws server). I had check that SO post before. The thing is the tunnels works for all other ports, whihch quite doesnt make sense to me. I just checked `/etc/mongod/conf` as well and it doesnt have any host restriction

Comment: Two things: 1) Port scan? (Admittedly something I'm not familiar with) but my next step would be to troubleshoot this specific port under the assumption some other process is currently using it. Did you find this in your search? https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/ and 2) In this file - `/etc/mongod.conf` you may have uncommented the `bindIp` but not the `security` line. Seems that's it...

Comment: @ThisClark No they are both _commented_ (as they should be right?) - I dont know how to port scan (im quite noob with all that) I mean i can connect no problem to the db when the client is on the server...

Comment: According to that post I linked, you should only comment out `bindIp` if you  enable authorization (uncomment `security`). And the wordage in that error message seems to suggest you need authorization in order to get "unprohibited."

Comment: @ThisClark You were right! Thanks a lot for the link !

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post:
https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/

You need to do three things:

1) Edit the MongoDB config file:

```
sudo vim /etc/mongod.conf
```

2) comment out the `bindIp` line:

```
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  <- comment out this line
```

3) uncomment the `security` line:

```
security:
  authorization: 'enabled'
```

Finally, you should have some authorization credentials that allow you to connect remotely (username/password or ssh key, etc).